# C++ output aligning with arrays

Tags: c++, alignment, output

I would like to align all the number at the end, but I can't seem to do it. Some help would be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please include the code, expected and actual output in the question as text

Comment: Images should not be used as primary information in a question or an answer because they A) are hard for future askers to search B) are opaque to the visually impaired C) are blocked by firewalls D) rot E) must be transcribed before they can be compiled and executed, often inserting new or fixing bugs F) are many times the size of their text equivalent. You should only use an image when the question is about the image, such as "Why is this pixel blue and not red?"

Answer (score 0):

setw(int) will set spacing between console output.  You'll need to store a dynamic integer determined by the length of the string that comes before it and the position of the column header.

I suggest you just use the [Boost.Format](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/format/index.html) library because setw can be a pain to use when your strings are dynamic in size.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to print some tabulators like:

```
cout << "idOfSalesman" << \t\t\t\t << "amount";
```

Problem is, tabulator has a fixed amount it will indent.
You will have to find a way to set one or more tabulator less/more if the name printed in the beginning is longer or shorter.
You could get the length of the string and divide by four (or the length of spaces a tab creates).
Now you know roughly how many tabs you need.